# Passing api key for all API automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

How to set api key for all API on reactjs/javascript?.I have problem with that

Comment: This would likely depend on what you use to make your API calls.

Comment: it's query param

Comment: jQuery? Options seem to be [these](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/all-possible-ways-of-making-an-api-call-in-plain-javascript-c0dee3c11b8b). For example, with Axios, you would add a request interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all boils down to the default headers for each request. Personally I would go like this

```
const defaultHeaders = {
  "Authorization": "Bear --some-secret-token--",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

const get = (url, params, headers) => {
  return fetch(
    url,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        ...defaultHeaders,
        ...headers,
      }
    }
  )
  .then(response => response.json())
};

const post = (url, body, headers) => {
  return fetch(
    url,
    {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      headers: {
        ...defaultHeaders,
        ...headers,
      }
    }
  )
  .then(response => response.json())
};

get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1,
  });
```

I export ready-to-use methods to cover some default headers.

If you use Axios, you can do like how @crashmstr suggested. But if you use regular fetch, this is definitely not a bad idea.